# Is there any system defined function to check if user has alter permission?

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I am using MS-sql server 2008

I need to know if a user id has "Alter Contraints" permission on one database.

Is there any system defined functions for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query will show you all the permissions a user has:

```
select * from fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'DATABASE')
```

You can also do specific tables, or an entire server.

http://sqltips.wordpress.com/2007/05/28/retreive-current-user-permissions-in-sql-server-2005/

Answer (score 2):

There is `HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen sys.fn_my_permissions?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176097.aspx

http://www.siusic.com/wphchen/list-all-permissions-a-user-has-in-sql-server-database-error-4064-321.html